# $ e^+e^- \longrightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$ probability density function of $\theta$ strange trend

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I'm considering the process: 
$$ e^+e^- \longrightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$$
The cross section in the center-of-mass frame:
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} \right)_{CoM}= \frac{\alpha^2}{4 s} \sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2_{\mu}}{s}} \left( 1+\frac{4m^2_{\mu}}{s} + \left( 1-\frac{4m^2_{\mu}}{s} \right)\cos^2\theta\right)
\end{equation}
Let's fix the parameter $\sqrt{s}=0.212$ GeV, I take $m_e=0$ for semplicity, but I' am not in the case of the ultra-high-energy limit so $m_{\mu} \neq 0$.

I want the probability density function of the observable $\theta$. 
$$ \Pr [\theta_1 \le \theta \le \theta_2] = \int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}} f(x) \, dx $$
$$f(x)= \frac{C}{\sigma_{total}}\left( \frac{d \sigma}{d x} \right)_{CoM}   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,C \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)=1$$
$$f(x)=\frac{2s}{\pi(4m_{\mu}^2+3s)}\left( 1+ \frac{4m^2_{\mu}}{s}+\left( 1-\frac{4m^2_{\mu}}{s} \right)\cos^2x \right)$$
Below are two graphs of the PDF by changing the range on the y axis.

[image]


[image]

I'm not at all sure that the result makes sense.

> In fact it would imply that there are no privileged directions.
>   The variability of the cross section is practically independent of the angle and therefore is at the end constant.

I do not think it could be that way but if it is not so I do not know where my mistake is.

Comment: You are computing the density function using the CoM, from that perspective all angles will look the same since momentum conservation means $p_{in}=0$, that is no direction is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral should be done over $d\Omega$.

Here is the differential cross section for the process.

$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
=\frac{\alpha^2}{16E^2}
\left(1+\cos^2\theta+\frac{m^2+M^2}{E^2}\sin^2\theta+\frac{m^2M^2}{E^4}\cos^2\theta\right)
$$

For $m=0$ we have

$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
=\frac{\alpha^2}{16E^2}
\left(1+\cos^2\theta+\frac{M^2}{E^2}\sin^2\theta\right)
$$

Let

$$
I(\xi)=2\pi\int_0^\xi\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\,\sin\theta\,d\theta,
\quad0\le\xi\le\pi
$$

The cumulative distribution function is

$$
F(\theta)=\frac{I(\theta)}{I(\pi)},
\quad0\le\theta\le\pi
$$

Hence

$$
P(\theta_1\le\theta\le\theta_2)=F(\theta_2)-F(\theta_1)
$$

The probability density is

$$
f(\theta)=\frac{dF(\theta)}{d\theta}
=\frac{2\pi}{I(\pi)}
\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)
\sin\theta,\quad0\le\theta\le\pi
$$

For $E=M$ this works out to

$$
f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta
$$

Here is a graph of $f(\theta)$.

[image: graph of pdf]

Comment: See http://www.eigenmath.org/muon-production.pdf for more.